# How to find all imports in code using typescript-eslint's parser and utils?

Tags: typescript, eslint, rules

I'm converting tslint custom rules to eslint custom rules. With tslint, we can easily find all imports with a single function 'findImports(..)', but with typescript-eslint, there is no function like this. My problem is, is there any alternative solution to this, or how to write functions like this.